# Does Appcelerator Titanium support Adaptive Icons in classic mobile app?

Tags: android, appcelerator, titanium-mobile, appcelerator-titanium

What I am trying to achieve is to have my appicon appear on Devices with Android Oreo and beyond, without the white circle mask seen [here](https://i0.wp.com/9to5google.com/wp-content/uploads/sites/4/2017/07/adaptive-icons-op-cover-e1501547493959.png?resize=1500%2C0&quality=82&strip=all&ssl=1). All of the Appicons I create with Android studio have circle backgrounds like the Slack Icon, but its shrunk like the Kindle Icon and surrounded by the outer white circle.

There is not much information (that I've found) pertaining to appcelerator specifically about these icons but what I have [found](https://jira.appcelerator.org/browse/TIMOB-24659) seems to suggest that their is no support [as of yet.](https://jira.appcelerator.org/browse/TIMOB-24688)

Until recently I was able to simply change the targeted APK of my app to 25. This would revert back to the old appicon style, but as of November 1st the Google Play Store requires all new apps and app updates to target Android Android SDK 26 or higher which then uses the adaptive icons.

Any guidance would be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score -1):

Just create one new classic titanium project and run it then check the app icon "DefaultIcon.png" come with rounded circle.

After run and get the thing is working fine according to your need, update your app icon according to "DefaultIcon.png" this is available in project hierarchy and replace with same name.

Please let me know again you have any issue.